# Array Elements In JavaScript Printing Into Seperate Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that accepts an array as the parameters, the function should console.log the array elements into a single array. But what I have is that the array element is printed into separate arrays. My code below

```
const result = []
function DNAStrand(dna){
    //your code here
    for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i++) {
        const element = dna[i];
        console.log(new Array(element))
    }
  }

  DNAStrand("AAAA") \\ is printing ['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A']
\\ Instead of ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and outputs?

Comment: I would say `const DNAStrand = dna => console.log(dna.split(''));`, but your question is unclear to me. It starts at "function that accepts an array", when you want to pass it a string, and i don't know what "console.log the array elements into a single array" is supposed to mean.

Comment: I edited the question to include the expected result

Comment: The code by ASDF is what you're looking for. `split('')` will split all single characters and create an array

Comment: If you don't want an individual array for each letter, you probably shouldn't create a `new Array(element)` for each letter in the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Array object first then insert the value in loop and finally do a Console.log after end of the loop.

```
const result = []
    function DNAStrand(dna) {
        //your code here
        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < dna.length; i++) {
            const element = dna[i];
            arr[i] = element;
        }
        console.log(arr)
    }

    DNAStrand("AAAA");
```

Comment: That is probably what the `result` array was intendet for

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't iterate through array, instead you can use `Array.from()` or `.split('')`

```
function DNAStrand(dna){

        console.log(Array.from(dna))

  }

  DNAStrand("AAAA")
```

or

```
function DNAStrand(dna){

        console.log(dna.split(''))

  }

  DNAStrand("AAAA")
```